# how to print an array backwards

Tags: c++, arrays

The user enteres a number which is put in an array and then the array needs to be orinted backwadrds

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[5];
    int x;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> x;
        numbers[x];
    }

    for (int i = 5; i>0 ; i--)
    {
        cout << numbers[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you compile with sufficient warnings, you should get something like *warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]*. Running the program compiled with Clang and `-fsanitize=undefined` gives *runtime error: index 5 out of bounds for type 'int [5]'*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because have fun.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're very close. Hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numbers[5];
    /* Get size of array */
    int size = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);
    int val;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> val;
        numbers[i] = val;
    }

    /* Start index at spot 4 and decrement until k hits 0 */
    for(int k = size-1; k >= 0; k--) {
        cout << numbers[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisD I was pretty close in some practice challenges. It was my similar section with the 2nd for loop with k >= 0. I was losing my last index place without the greater than or equal to

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //get size of the array
    int arr[1000], n;
    cin >> n;
    //receive the elements of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    //swap the elements of indexes
    //the condition is just at "i*2" be cause if we exceed these value we will start to return the elements to its original places 
    for (int  i = 0; i*2< n; i++)
    {
        //variable x as a holder for the value of the index 
        int x = arr[i];
        //index arr[n-1-i]: "-1" as the first index start with 0,"-i" to adjust the suitable index which have the value to be swaped
        arr[i] = arr[n - 1 - i];
        arr[n - 1 - i] = x;
    }
    //loop for printing the new elements
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it is my first answer to a question here. so I did not know how to answer perfectly :) .

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to your result but you did little mistakes, the following code is the correct solution of the code you have written.

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[5];
    int x;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    for (int i = 4; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout << numbers[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

//print numbers in an array in reverse order
int myarray[1000];
cout << "enter size: " << endl;
int size;
cin >> size;
cout << "Enter numbers: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    cin >> myarray[i];
}

for (int i = size - 1; i >=0; i--)
{
    cout << myarray[i];
}

return 0;

}
```

of course you can just delete the cout statements and modify to your liking

Answer (score 0):

this one is more simple

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{

int a[10], x, i;

cout << "enter the size of array" << endl;

cin >> x;
  cout << "enter the element of array" << endl;

for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {

cin >> a[i];

}

cout << "reverse of array" << endl;

for (i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--)

cout << a[i] << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

answer in c++. using only one array.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;




int main()
{

        int array[1000] , count ;

        cin >> count ;

        for(int i = 0 ; i<count ; i++)
            {

                cin >> array[i] ;
            }

        for(int j = count-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
            {
                cout << array[j] << endl;
            }
            
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int array[10000];
    int N;

    cout<< " Enter total numbers ";
    cin>>N;

    cout << "Enter  numbers:"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <N; ++i)                                           
    {
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    for ( i = N-1; i>=0;i--)
    {                                                             
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```