# c++ Segmentation fault when trying to reverse print an array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a array consisting of chars like [1,2,3,4,5,.,..] and I have a loop that looks like

```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    os << data[i]; // os is std::ostream&
```

This loop prints the array in the correct order without any errors. But when I use this loop to print it backwards

```
  for (size_t i = (size - 1); i >= 0; --i)
    os << data[i];
```

I get a segmentation fault error. Any reason why this can happen?

Comment: `size_t`, as you know, is an unsigned value. Can you think of any unsigned value that is negative?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the type. Is there another way this could be made to work?

Comment: I would use a type int for i, but if you can't. Then I guess you can use a break statement once i = 0 after the os << data[i].

Comment: Of course there's a way to make it work using `size_t`. You just have to understand that `size_t` cannot be negative, and adjust your logic accordingly. You can use a do-while loop, with the comparison done using a post-decrement operator, or still use a `for` loop, but compare for `> 0`, and decrement at the beginning of the loop, not at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `i >= 0` is always true (because `size_t` is an unsigned type). You've written an infinite loop.

Doesn't your compiler warn you about that? I know `g++ -Wextra` does here.

What you can do instead is this:

```
for (size_t i = size; i--; ) {
    os << data[i];
}
```

This uses post-decrement to be able to check the old value of `i`, which allows the loop to stop just after `i = 0` (at which point `i` has wrapped around to `SIZE_MAX`).

Comment: I followed the instructions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834885/how-to-print-an-array-backwards

Comment: It doesn't give any warning unfortunately.

Comment: What part of those instructions advised you to use a `size_t`?

Comment: @SarahHyland What compiler are you using?

Comment: G++ C++11, it has -Wall and -Wextra enabled.

Comment: @SarahHyland [Can't reproduce](https://tio.run/##NY7LCoMwFET3@YqBgi8quK2v3@imUEKM9oJGSWIpLf5600TpLObegcMwYlnyQQjnTqTEuHYSNc3GasmnlrHVkBpgbFeWht7ybivGSFlMnFQSHq4HcYZ4cI0s8@GZ4sPgRT2SkBFFO4S2QZFCS7tqhaLaoX7WSI5iEBpcKn8CWCHP6V8VtE8Q82pR157xFt9UfLRsbHPuK/qRD8blVz6O3uXLav4D). It says `.code.tio.cpp:7:26: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]`

Comment: This works but for some reason, it leaves out one character which was the first character in the normal array. For example if the normal array is 123456, it prints 65432.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is unsigned int so it always remain positive, so your loop is an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use a C++ for-in loop to avoid the problem.  Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using boost::adaptors::reverse;

int main()
{
  auto v = vector<char>{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'X' };

  char const* sep = "";
  for (auto c : v)
  {
    cout << sep << c;
    sep = " ";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  sep = "";
  for (auto c : reverse(v))
  {
    cout << sep << c;
    sep = " ";
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```